# Does Graph APIs provided by meta for developers useful for access whatsapp business details

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

Recently I was exploring Graph APIs(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview) offered by Meta, while checking through couple of APIs like /message-id and /conversation-id for whatsapp message which I sent to one of my contact number (this contact number I am using as customer number) this APIs are working, instead they are showing error message as follows 'Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{message-id goes here}' does not exist'.

Likewise I am getting same error while trying to fetch details about {conversation-id} which I fetched from webhook, which I integrated to receive notifications about message which I will receive from customer.

Also, a point to note is that.. while reading through Graph API documentation for /messages as well as /conversation APIs is says 'An individual message in a Messenger or Instagram Messaging conversation.' and 'A Messenger conversation between a person and a Facebook Page or an Instagram Professional Account.' does this means this Graph APIs is only accessing for data which is shared over facebook page/messages and/or instagram messages.

What I am trying to acheive using Graph API is to get conversation details for whatsapp business API happened between customer and business.

Please help clear my above concerns.

Thanks,
Abhishek